# Adding WIndows Firewall exclusions for Windows Subsystem for Android

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, firewall

I've searched all over for this answer, but my WSA somehow got botched and can't get past the firewall. I get a VirtWifi Adapter can't connect to the internet, and my firewall log shows:
2022-02-27 00:36:42 DROP UDP 172.17.193.190 172.17.192.1 29070 53 75 - - - - - - - RECEIVE 4088

If I turn off public firewall it works, so it may be a profile issue, but the one place Windows Subsystem for Android appeared in my firewall settings (outbound) it had both selected. I've since deleted that since outbound usually means block, and added my own outbound allows.

Lots of Q&A pages say the firewall is the problem, but none of them say how to actually fix it. I've added incoming and outgoing allows for WSAclient.exe and WSAservice.exe to no avail. Any ideas on how to get this reset would be appreciated.